# Pass Swift uuid_t to a C function

Tags: swift, swift3, uuid, bridging-header

Using Swift, how do I pass UUID to a C function that takes a uuid_t?

Let's say I have the following function declared in my bridging header:

```
bool my_set_uuid(uuid_t uuid);
```

And in Swift I'm attempting to pass it a new UUID:

```
let uuid = UUID()
my_set_uuid(uuid.uuid)
```

I get the following error: "Cannot convert value of type 'uuid_t' (aka '(UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)') to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer!'"

I know this is because UUID.uuid is of type uuid_t which is implemented as a C array of 16 bytes, which becomes a tuple of 16 UInt8s in Swift. But why can't I pass a C uuid_t to C? It seems to be expecting a pointer.

So, I try creating a pointer to my uuid with withUnsafeMutableBytes. I found this worked:

```
let _: UInt8 = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &uuid.0) { ptr in
    my_set_uuid(ptr)
    return 0
}
```

But I've also read that &uuid.0 is unsafe because I'm using the entire tuple (as an array) in my C function. Also, all the dressing up I had to do with `let _: UInt8` and `return 0` seems wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed unsafe, using `&uuid.0` in such a way. As Swift compiler may create a copy of the single element in a temporary region, and pass the address of the region to the function. This may not happen in optimized code, but you cannot predict what code Swift generates.

To make your code safe, you may need to write something like this:

```
    let uuid = UUID()
    var rawUuid = uuid.uuid
    // (You can rewrite the two lines above into a sigle line as `var rawUuid = UUID().uuid`
    let result = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &rawUuid) {uuidPtr in
        uuidPtr.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: MemoryLayout<uuid_t>.size) {bytePtr in
            my_set_uuid(bytePtr)
        }
    }
```

(`result` gets the value of `my_set_uuid(bytePtr)`. If you want to ignore the result, replace `let result` to `_`.)

`uuid_t` is a fixed sized array type in C, which is something hard to work with in Swift. Maybe tuple type in Swift should have better ways to handle this sort of use cases.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
    let uuid = UUID().uuidString        
    _ = uuid.withCString { s1 in
        my_set_uuid(UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: s1))
    }
```

Comment: I want to pass the 16 bytes of the UUID, not the UUID as a string.

Comment: so use `UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: s1)` to pass the 16 bytes

Comment: Please explain how